# Not receiving push notification on android with parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am very new to android app development. I am using parse.com for my backend, and I have followed the tutorial https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications to set up push notifications. However, whenever I send a notification using parse notification console (on the website) or from an android device, I do not receive any notification. Secondly, on the parse notification console, each notification shows 0 as pushes sent. And when I checked the registration ID in the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation, it is empty. Even GCMSenderID is empty. So I am suspecting that my app is not getting registered properly, but installationID field is not empty. I have added all permissions and credentials in the manifest file.

Please help me. It will be a big help. Thank you :)

Here's my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: If you change the package name of this sample app, change
  "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the
  lines below to match the new package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.parse.swipeit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.swipeit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.parse.swipeit.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.swipeit.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: If you change the package name of this sample app,
              change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" in the lines
              below to match the new package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.parse.swipeit" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: @StephanBranczyk please check the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is important.

```
<!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package
 name. -->
```

You need to use the Google developer console to enable the Google Cloud Messaging api for you. For that, you'll need to use your own unique valid package name (that only belongs to you and no one else).

Comment: I have already put my app's package name. "com.parse.starter" is the package name, but still its not working

Comment: No, that package name "com.parse.starter" doesn't belong to you. It belongs to parse.com and Google knows that. You must use a different package name throughout your application.

Comment: I started a new project with a different package name. Again when I am running it, the app does register itself, but the deviceToken field is still empty. So when I send a push notification, it shows 0 as pushes sent. I have changed the manifest in the question to the new manifest. so you can check that again

Comment: it's working now. You were right. I completely changed my package name and it is working :) thanks :)

Comment: @user2709885  can u share how u resolved ? i m still failed to recieve notification on device

Comment: @Erum, I can help you. What package name are you using in your manifest?

Comment: i m using my application package name can u pls create any SO chat so that we can do communication there @StephanBranczyk

Comment: kindly come here and ping me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71661/android-discussions

Comment: @Erum, Sorry, but if you're already using your own package name, you're not having the same problem as the original asker of this question. I know it doesn't look that way to you right now, but that's because the original asker edited their own question.  This is not a question for chat, you should ask your own separate question, with your own manifest at the very least, plus any logcat errors you're getting (assuming you've already studied at all the other questions with similar problems to yours and you couldn't find what you were looking for).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk  yes i m getting issues regarding sending push notification to the user i m sending it by passing username is it correct way to send ?